# is facebook cookie persistent or not?

Tags: c#, facebook, cookies

My question is how to find out if a facebook user is logged in persistently(clicked on keep me logged in button before logging in) or not. I would imagine that this would be reflected in the facebook cookie. That means that this would create a persistent cookie on the client machine, with an expiration date.

If what I am saying is true, how can I check the cookie if it is persistent or not(having expiration date or not) in C# language, if not how do I find out if the user is persistently logged in or not?

Comment: Why do you need to know this ?

Comment: because when the user closes the browser or tab I have to log out of a server, and destroy/keep my personal(not facebook) application cookie depending on if he/she has been persistently signed in or not.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I check the cookie if it is persistent or not(having expiration date or not)

The information on how long to store a cookie is transmitted to the browser, but you don’t have access to that information via client side technologies like JavaScript. You would have to write an addon or something to get access to that kind of information.

> if not how do I find out if the user is persistently logged in or not?

Not at all, I’d guess.